# Tensorflow overwrites scope in custom layer

Tags: tensorflow, scope

I am trying to implement a noisy linear layer in tensorflow, inheriting from tf.keras.layers.Layer . Everything works fine except for reusing variables. This seems to stem from some issue with the scoping: Whenever i use the add_weight function from the superclass and a weight with the same name already exists, it seems to ignore the given reuse-flag in the scope and creates a new variable instead. Interestingly, it does not add a 1 to the variable name in the end as usual in similar cases, but rather adds the 1 to the scope name.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class NoisyDense(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,output_dim):
        self.output_dim=output_dim

        super(NoisyDense, self).__init__()

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.input_dim = input_shape.as_list()[1]
        self.noisy_kernel = self.add_weight(name='noisy_kernel',shape=  (self.input_dim,self.output_dim))

def noisydense(inputs, units):

    layer = NoisyDense(units)

    return layer.apply(inputs)

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, 10),name="inputs")



scope="scope"
with tf.variable_scope(scope):
    inputs3 = noisydense(inputs,
           1)
    my_variable = tf.get_variable("my_variable", [1, 2, 3],trainable=True)


with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    inputs2 = noisydense(inputs,
           1)
    my_variable = tf.get_variable("my_variable", [1, 2, 3],trainable=True)

tvars = tf.trainable_variables()



init=tf.global_variables_initializer()    
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    tvars_vals = sess.run(tvars)

for var, val in zip(tvars, tvars_vals):
    print(var.name, val)
```

This results in the variables

```
  scope/noisy_dense/noisy_kernel:0
   scope_1/noisy_dense/noisy_kernel:0
   scope/my_variable:0
```

being printed. I would like it to reuse the noisy kernel instead of creating a second one, as it is done for my_variable.

Comment: Can you please reformat the code properly because right now I am not able to reproduce your result?

Comment: Should work now.